# Select limit percent

Tags: mysql, sql

I want
 example 10% of records in table 
not 10 records
This query run in SQL Server

```
select top 10 percent * from tablename
```

Why this query in MySQL do not run?

```
select top 10 percent * from tablename
```

Comment: Because the syntax is different use `LIMIT 10` at end ;).

Comment: TOP is MS SQL Server specific. MySQL has LIMIT instead (at the end).

Comment: SQL is not unified between its implementations, it is not hard to find equivalents on the internet though

Comment: then you have to select the count of entries first and then take 10% of that number and do a select with limit.

Comment: please more explain by matacode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it with a subquery, this is pretty basic since you want everything in one table:

```
SELECT *
FROM    (
    SELECT tablename.*, @counter := @counter +1 AS counter
    FROM (select @counter:=0) AS initvar, tablename
    ORDER BY value DESC   
) AS X
where counter <= (10/100 * @counter);
ORDER BY value DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL use `order by` or `limit`

```
select * from tablename order by percent desc limit 10
```

> TOP clause works on `MSSQL server` not `sql`.

Comment: I want example 10% of records in table